# Get the CRL so that I can check over it to see if a cert is revoked?

Tags: java, x509certificate

I am trying to work out how to go about the task of getting the CRL so that I can then iterate over it and check my cert to see if it is revoked.

I have been researching for days now, and read tons of oracle documentation, but all I have really learned is what the individual components are. I have absolutely no idea where to begin coding it and really need some guidance.

What I want to do, is somehow get the list of revoked certificates, then work over it to see my my given cert is revoked.

Or is there an easier way than that? What am I missing here?

Comment: Java can already do this [automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/cert3.html). You don't have to code it yourself.

Comment: How do I get that to happen though?

I get that I can have it do .checkValidity() and do a simple date check - but how do I check for revocation?

Comment: You get it to happen by following the steps in the link I provided.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I need to be checking programmatically, if a cert has been revoked or not.